# Is it grammatically correct sentence - "I did able to do that"?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say - "I did able to do that" ? to stress the fact that I was able to do something in the past but some reason I am not able to do this right now.

Comment: You mean you used to be able to do it?

Comment: Right. I mean I have done it at least once in the past.

Comment: Can't we say -- "There was a time when I was able to do it, but not anymore".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The word *did* is an "auxiliary" verb (sometimes called a "helping" verb) that is only meaningful when followed by another "main" verb. However, *able* is an adjective, not a verb. You should use the proper form of the verb *be* instead:

> I was able to do that.

If you are trying to avoid the simple past tense in order to stress that you are no longer have this ability, you could use the past perfect

> I had been able to do that.

However, in either case, explicitly stating the time frame makes your sentence clearer.

> Last year, I was able to do that.
>
> Last year, I had been able to do that.

Even better, you could specify when you stopped having this ability.

> I was able to do that until the accident.
>
> I had been able to do that until the accident.